# Adding Custom ViewFlipper in Widget does not work to show?

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-appwidget

As per [android.developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) site `ViewFlipper` support as `RemoreViews` So i decide to make one simple Widget which show fix images and i want user to make then start and stop by providing `Button`.

Now my problem is `ViewFlipper` does not have `startFlipping()` and `stopFlipping()` method as RemoteMethod, So decide to use my own Custom `ViewFlipper` to call `startFlipping()` and `stopFlipping()` by my self from `setFlipInterval` because it is RemoteMethod.

Here is my Custom `ViewFlipper` Class .

```
@RemoteView
public class PhotoViewFliper extends ViewFlipper {

    public static final int STOP_FLIP = -11;

    public static final int START_FLIP = -12;

    public String TAG = PhotoViewFliper.class.getCanonicalName();

    public PhotoViewFliper(Context _Context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(_Context);
    }

    public PhotoViewFliper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void stopFlipping() {

        super.stopFlipping();
        Log.d(TAG, "stopFlipping--My Called ");
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFlipInterval(int milliseconds) {

        Log.d(TAG, "setFlipInterval--My Called " + milliseconds);
        switch (milliseconds) {

        case STOP_FLIP:
            stopFlipping();
            Log.d(TAG, "In Side Switch stopFlipping--My Called ");
            break;
        case START_FLIP:
            startFlipping();

            Log.d(TAG, "In Side Switch startFlipping--My Called ");

            break;
        default:
            super.setFlipInterval(milliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my layout use in `Widget`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <com.photos.widget.PhotoViewFliper
        android:id="@+id/vflipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_boarder"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/in_from_right"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/out_to_left" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_examples" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tad_logo_com" />
    </com.photos.widget.PhotoViewFliper>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_play_pause"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_av_pause_over_video" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Below  is my Error Logtag

```
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.photos.widget.PhotoViewFliper
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2415)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:402)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:54)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:408)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:104)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.photos.widget.PhotoViewFliper" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
03-13 01:56:48.555: W/AppWidgetHostView(1420):  ... 16 more
```

Comment: Where you have kept the `PhotoViewFliper` file ? Or Are you using the library for this ?

Answer (score 0):

read this carefuly: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

"Descendants of these classes are not supported."

Comment: That mean i can not use by extending `ViewFlipper` in `RemoteViews`.

Comment: Then how i can stop ViewFlipper to being Flipping?

Comment: never tried that but maybe RemoteViews.showNext/showPrevious would help

Comment: if the above wont help, you could try using AdapterViewFlipper, since showNext/showPrevious are used by this widget

Comment: For AdaperViewFlipper i have not check it but i check is source code and it does not have `stopFlipping()` method as `RemoreViewMoethod`.So even i use that it can not able to stop it's flipping.